# Can we configure presto's data base connector information from its GUI

Tags: presto

I am using presto version 179 and I need to manually create a `database.properties` file in `/etc/presto/catalog` through the CLI. 
Can I do the same process from the GUI of presto?

Answer (score 0):

Presto's built-in web interface does not provide any configuration capabilities.
Usually, such things are handled as part of deployment/configuration management on a cluster. Thus, configuration is provided by some external means just as is Presto installation.